# Choosing between ESP32 and Arduino Pro Mini

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, esp32

This is probably a fundamental question but I am hoping to get some pointers on how to chose between Arduino Pro Mini and ESP 32.

I am hoping to make a wrist based wearable like fitbit. Three primary needs are

1. Accelerometer or MPU module is important to collect movement data.
2. Wi-fi is not important because I think bluetooth would be enough to sync the data to a cell phone.
3. Battery management is of course more critical as I want it to last longer.
4. Smaller the dimensions, better for design and aesthetics.

My first choice was using Arduino  pro mini because it is smaller and less  power consuming.  However, we do need to manually connect BLE module like HC-05 to it. Now I think ESP32 could also be a good option because it has both wifi and bluetooth although I do not care about wifi.

Now I found these useful comparisons on web

1. Arduino and NodeMcu (ESP8266) like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/8elsur/arduino_uno_vs_nodemcu/)
2. Between ESP32 vs ESP8266 like [this](https://makeradvisor.com/esp32-vs-esp8266/)
3. Between Nano or pro mini like [this](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=545132.0)

However, none of them help me directly in my case. I understand ESP32 and ProMini are meant for different things and hence should not be compared for a single project. May be I am missing something more fundamental. Any guidelines in this would really help.

Comment: why not compare with nRF5? 32bit ARM Cortex M0 with Bluetooth

Comment: Absolutely. I was about to suggest the same thing. Something like the nRF51822 would be a far better fit for your project.